# Creating headers for a list in haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have the following piece of haml code

```
%dt= 'Properties'
%dd{title: 'Properties'}
  - config[:Properties].each do |key, values|
    %p
      %em
        %b= t('.Key')
      = key
      %em
        %b= t('.Value')
      = values
```

here rather than making it `key "..."  value " ..."` for each and every key/value pair. I would like to make the key and value as a list header . Such that

```
Key  value 

...   ....
...   ....
...   ....
```

Anyone have any suggestion on how i can achieve this ?

Comment: Can you give an example of the HTML output you want to get?

Answer (score 2):

Did you meant a table with 2 columns? Listing all the possible key/value pair inside?

Here it is:

```
%table
  - config[:properties].each do |key, value|
    %tr
      %td= key
      %td= value
```

You can even add the `theader` and `tbody` tags if you want:

```
%table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th= 'Key'
      %td= 'Value'
  %tbody
    - config[:properties].each do |key, value|
      %tr
        %td= key
        %td= value
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply ..but i want the same for a list

Comment: Just a simple bold Key and a value header would suffice

Comment: @user814733 I don't fully understand your request... Do you mean having 2 table headers, with only the cell "Key" in bold?